# VS2012 Debugging, dont step into certain custom routines

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2012

i have routines that are used often that I dont want to step into in debugger.
Ideally treated much the same way as unmanaged code is.

getting the F10/F11 combinations right is distracting and annoying and is followed by Shift F11. And 1 Shift F11 too many and you are ready to plant your fist through the screen.
So after yet another round of expletives, Im looking for a solution or tip on how to avoid this issue.

Is there a class or method annotation?  Something I can do so that F11 steps over and not into certain classes or Methods ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about the [DebuggerStepThroughAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggerstepthroughattribute.aspx) which tells the debugger to step over the code.

Comment: Just tested it...gold. Works a treat. Thanks Don

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing special about unmanaged code debugging in this respect. Other than the higher likelihood that you won't have PDB file (or a stripped one) for code that you are not interested in. That works the same in C#.  Project + Properties, Build tab, Advanced button, Debug Info setting.

Additional options when debugging C# is the "Just My Code" and "Step over properties and operators" options in Tools + Options, Debugging section and the [DebuggerStepThrough] attribute.  The "Just My Code" option was added to C++ for VS2013.

Comment: the just my code option will be useful with the attribute.   I just tested it too.. Thanks Hans. +1 for useful info.